# why am i getting an inputmismatchexception?

Tags: java

Im just trying to get it to print the information in a txt file but i keep running into 
this problem and idk how to fix it. I commented out the inFile which im only pointing out so i can fill this with text so i can post this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class P175ex6 {
static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main (String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException{
    //Scanner inFile=new Scanner(new FileReader("prog.dat"));
    PrintWriter outFile=new PrintWriter("prog.txt");
    double gross,fedtax,statetax,sstax,medcare_caidtax,pensionplan,healthinsur,netpay;
    String name;
    System.out.println("Please input employee name");
    name=console.next();
    System.out.println("Please input employee gross pay");
    gross=console.nextDouble();
```

I get this error message when it asks for the gross pay?

```
Please input employee name
Bill Robinson
Please input employee gross amount
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at P175ex6.main(P175ex6.java:14)
```

Comment: show us what you entered into the console.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that the exception is being thrown on this line:

```
gross = console.nextDouble();
```

So whatever you inputted is not a proper double.

EDIT:

The previous answer is incorrect. It's actually because of this line:

```
console.next();
```

This only reads the next token, which is "Bill" This causes `console.nextDouble()` to read "Robinson" causing the error.

To fix, replace `console.next()` with `console.nextLine()`.

Comment: I never get to enter anything the error comes with the " please enter gross amount" question before anything can be entered

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious. it was expecting a double for employee pay and you entered a string.

I modified your code and tried it in eclipse and got no error -

```
package foo;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class P175ex6 {
static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main (String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException{
    double gross;
    String name;
    System.out.println("Please input employee name");
    name=console.next();
    System.out.println("Please input employee gross pay");
    gross=console.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

**Console -**

```
Please input employee name
bing
Please input employee gross pay
111
```

Comment: i dont get to enter anything it asks "please enter gross amount" and then the error occurs. i enter in bill robinson for the name string and then i want it to ask to enter the gross pay and then u enter a double. but it asks the question and then error and never allows anything to be entered

Comment: lol nvm i figured it out i didnt think about it only checking the first string and not the second the space i put in between name was my problem. thank you for your help.

Comment: java programming from problem analysis to program design